# How can Mathematica merge $(1/t)^{1/3} t^{17/3}$ in an expression?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, variable

`(1/t)^(1/3) t^(17/3)`
How to let Mathematica simplify it?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please copy Mathematica code directly from the input cell of your notebook, click on the `Edit` button under your post and paste in the right location. There is a `{  }` icon available in the palette to format it as code. Unless we can experiment with your actual code in our own notebook sessions, it is hard to offer much concrete advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Assuming[t \[Element] PositiveReals,
 Simplify@((1/t)^(1/3)) t^(17/3) ]
```

$t^{16/3}$

*Mathematica* will not simplify---indeed *cannot* simplify---the term if $t$ is negative or imaginary.

Comment: Similarly: FullSimplify[(1/t)^(1/3) t^(17/3), t > 0]

Answer (score 2):

```
(1/t)^(1/3) t^(17/3) // PowerExpand
```

> t^(16/3)